# WUA and WSUS disagreeing on update GUID

Tags: windows-update, automatic-updates

I have encountered updates that are marked as needed by WUA with update GUIDs that do not match the GUIDs for the same updates in WSUS. The WSUS server is synchronizing all Products and Categories and all languages.

So the question is how could WUA know of a patch that WSUS does not (or that WSUS identifies by a different GUID)?

One example is Windows Internet Explorer 9 for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems:
 •WUA update GUID: d8ba5dbf-aade-4125-bbdf-48dcc5950131
•WSUS update GUID: bd9f0b80-866f-4ded-a6d9-ed74da717519

For patch management solutions that rely on the update GUID to be consistent between WUA and WSUS this poses a challenge to say the least.

Thanks for any help in advance,

Shady

Comment: Most likely it is a Bundled Update

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark but perhaps it is a different revision? the IUpdateIdentity interface defines both a id GUID and a revision number.

[IUpdateIdentity API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I'm intrigued myself why this would happen.